# EDIT: ODE Derivation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let 
$k'(t)=sAk(t)^{\alpha}-(n+{\delta})k(t)$.

Substitute 
$x(t)=k(t)^{(1-{\alpha})}$.

One obtains the linear ODE 
$x'(t)=(1-{\alpha})sA-(1-{\alpha})(n+{\delta})x(t)$.

How do we get there step-by-step; I'm confused in particular about the coefficient $(1-{\alpha})$?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is a Bernoulli type ODE. Look it up on wikipedia they should have a detailed derivation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the equation 
$$
k'(t) = sA[k(t)]^a - (n + \delta)k(t)\tag 1
$$
Putting
$$
x(t) = [k(t)]^{1-a}\tag 2
$$
Differentiating (Derivative of Composite Functions/Chain Rule) we find
$$
x'(t)=(1 - a)[k(t)]^{1-a-1}k'(t)=(1 - a)[k(t)]^{- a}k'(t)
$$
and multiplying by $[k(t)]^{a}$
$$
x'(t)[k(t)]^{a}=(1 - a)k'(t)
$$
that is $$k'(t)=\frac{x'(t)[k(t)]^{a}}{(1 - a)}\tag 3$$ and substituting (3) in (1) we have
$$
\frac{x'(t)[k(t)]^{a}}{1 - a}= sA[k(t)]^a - (n + \delta)k(t)
$$

Dividing by $[k(t)]^{a}$ and multiplying by $1-a$ we have
$$
x'(t)= (1 - a)sA[k(t)]^a[k(t)]^{-a} - (1 - a)(n + \delta)k(t)[k(t)]^{-a}
$$
and observing that $k(t)[k(t)]^{-a}=[k(t)]^{1-a}=x(t)$ we finally have
$$
x'(t)= (1 - a)sA - (1 - a)(n + \delta)x(t)
$$

Comment: Quite a clear one after all; Thanks!